# Responding to a click event in an Android custom user view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, touch-event

I am creating an Android 4.0 app and need some help.

I have extended RelativeLayout to be zoomable/pannable via the code I found here:

[Android - zoom in/out RelativeLayout with spread/pinch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013906/android-zoom-in-out-relativelayout-with-spread-pinch)
and here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438004/1458279

I have created my own custom user view (SectionView) that I have placed in my ZoomableRelativeLayout and I've written an Activity that uses this layout.

I'm overriding onTouchEvent in my ZoomableRelativeLayout and I'm able to detect when a user has "clicked" rather than started to "drag" by looking at the duration between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP.
see: [How to distinguish between move and click in onTouchEvent()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965695/how-to-differ-between-move-and-click-in-ontouchevent)

So.. I know when the ZoomableRelativeLayout was clicked - now, how do I turn that "click" into some event on the SectionView control (if one of the SectionView controls is beneath the finger doing the clicking) so I can detect it from the Activity.

What I've done so far -

In the instance when I've detected a click on my ZoomableRelativeLayout I am setting onTouchEvent to return FALSE - as I understand this means it hasn't been handled, so I expected other touch events for controls within the RelativeLayout to be able to handle them instead.

However, no matter what I try I don't seem to be able to get my SectionView control to respond to Touch Events in order to raise an event in the Activity .

I'm not an Android expert so I'm possibly missing something really obvious - PLEASE help preferably with a simple example as I've been working on this for ages and I don't feel like I'm getting anywhere.

Thanks