# Should I use GestureDetector or a custom solution to detect click/tap and moving?

Tags: android, gestures

I simply want an element to be draggable and clickable. Would `GestureDetector` be sufficient? There are many questions (and answers) on how to distinguish between movements and clicks, I've also read many tutorial that use custom implementations, which makes wonder, is there's something wrong with `GestureDetector`? Are there cases where I should write a custom solution instead of using a `GestureDetector`?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19788836/4021051) is an example for a custom solution.

P.S., English is not my first language. Feel free to rephrase the question and correct any grammar or spelling mistakes.